# Verify text of a particular css value using capybara + selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm to verify the text of a particular css value.

HTML is as -

```
    <table class="resp_card_table company-dashboard">
     <thead>...</thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="company in company | filter:searchString" class="ng-scope">
       <td data-label="Company Name" class="ng-binding">ABC Constructions</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

I'm to verify "Company Name" to have text "ABC Constructions"

How can I do this using expect statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Capybara repo: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec

> ...Capybara matchers are also supported in view specs:
>
> ```
> RSpec.describe "todos/show.html.erb", type: :view do
>   it "displays the todo title" do
>     assign :todo, Todo.new(title: "Buy milk")
>     render
>
>     expect(rendered).to have_css("header h1", text: "Buy milk")
>   end
> end
> ```

Given your HTML, try this:

```
expect(rendered).to have_css(
  'td[data-role="Company Name"]', text: 'ABC Constructions'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do it in a view spec then the answer by aridlehoover would be correct.  Howver, in a feature/system spec (where you would normally be using selenium with capybara) then it would be

```
expect(page).to have_css('td[data-role="Company Name"]', text: 'ABC Constructions')
```

Note that that the text option will (by default) match substrings (contains rather than equals) so it would also match on an element that had the text contents of 'ABC Constructions Company'.  If you want to exactly match 'ABC Constructions' then you can do

```
expect(page).to have_css('td[data-role="Company Name"]', text: 'ABC Constructions', exact_text: true)
```

or more succinctly

```
expect(page).to have_css('td[data-role="Company Name"]', exact_text: 'ABC Constructions')
```